# 'Fiddler.FiddlerApplication' does not contain a definition for 'Startup'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, fiddler, fiddlercore

I'm building an asp.net application in visual studio 2013(Update 4, .net framework version 4.5.1) and plugging fiddler functionality in it using fiddlercore library( fiddler version 4.5.1.2 ). I get following build error :

**'Fiddler.FiddlerApplication' does not contain a definition for 'Startup'**

No other errors. Looking at object browser I found that Startup method is missing there also.

What is the solution for this problem?

Comment: maybe crate a now solution and add the .DLL again and try

Comment: Thanks ! I found the solution. I have attached fiddler reference instead of fiddlercore.dll in references.

Comment: Really Happy to solve this problem